# VScode - Python extension - Change default language

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The [Microsoft Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python), for `Visual Studio Code`, chooses by itself at installation time which language it will use. I guess it chooses the language of the OS, which is French in my case. My `VSCode` installation is in English. Is it possible to install the extension in a different language ? I would like it to be in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue. Here's how to fix it :

1. Open the `"locale.json"` file ( Command Palette > Configure Display
   Language ).
2. Change `"locale":"en"` to `"locale":"fr"`.
3. Restart`VSCode`.
4. Re-open the `"locale.json"` file. Change back your locale to English
   : `"locale":"en"`.
5. Restart`VSCode`.

Now the extension's commands ( in command palette ) should be in English!

Answer (score 0):

The [locale documentation for VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales) says how to set it.

Comment: I want to change the language of the python extension, not visual studio.

Comment: You can't change the locale _just_ for the extension; we get the locale from VS Code itself.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer, I'll have to deal with a visual studio code in english and the extension in french. Not a big deal but I had liked to have all in english.

Comment: @nikau6 are you saying that you _want_ the extension in French but VS Code in English, or that _right now_ they differ and you want them both to be in English? If it's the latter then that might be a bug in the extension.

Comment: I want them both to be in english. My visual studio code is in english but the extension is in french. And by the way, my Ubuntu installation is in French

Comment: @nikau6 there's a [bug we reported to VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3307) related to locales which they are still trying to fix.

Comment: That's it ! That's what my problem is. Thank you for the link.